# Deny access to a file with a specific extension

Tags: .htaccess, server, plesk

My problem concerns server with Windows Server and Plesk.

I upload to my FTP files concerning Babylon.js model. If i go to path where i upload file i see something like this:

[image]

When i click to first file (JPG File - 141_light parquet texture-seamless_hr.jpg), third file (manifest file - untitled.babylon.manifest) and fourth file its normally open in the browser. But when i click in .babylon file i got error:

[image]

I suppose somewhere in Plesk it should specify the type of file that I can open, unfortunately I have no idea where. Or maybe adding a .htacces file could fix the problem?

What i do:

1. In all file and directiory i got it correct permissions
2. In plesk -> IIS Server Setiings I set enable Directory Browsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for 5 hour, but when i ask this question i found answer in 2 minutes :)

1. In plesk go to **Websites & Domains -> example.com -> Hosting & DNS IIS Settings**
2. In **MIME types window** I add `application/babylon .babylon`